# I want to get the file name stored in database to the jTable

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, jtable

I have linked the jTable with my sql database successfully. All the data in the database table are shown in the jTable. But under the columns **DocumentFile** and **Photo** in the jTable some codes are shown instead of their names. **I want to get the relevant document name and photo name stored in sql database instead of those codes.**

Heres part of my code that consists of the query...

```
public ViewAccounts() {
        initComponents();
        ViewTable();
    }

     private void ViewTable(){
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

        try{

            query = "SELECT * FROM tourClient";

            PreparedStatement stm = db.getconn().prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();
            View_Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }


    }
```

I cannot upload a pic here, they wont allow me to since i have less reputation.

Heres what I have in my table tourClient.

ClientID,Name,Age,Nationality,Address,Email,PhoneNo,PassportNo,InsuaranceNo,FoodReq,HealthReq,NextOfKin,DocumentFile,Photo

They all work fine except for document and photo which shows some codes

Comment: Could you include a short example of what is in `tourClient`?

Comment: I have typed whats in tourClient.  :)

Comment: Thank you! Could you also give an example row of data inside? It could help understand. As well as the type of DocumentFile and Photo! :-)

Comment: Presumably these "codes" are linked some where in another table, you will need to change your select statement to include those values in your query "as" columns

Comment: what are the datatypes of DocumentFile and Photo columns...if they are in BLOB or CLOB format then you have to create child of `JTableCellRenderer` class and set this class to your JTable column class of DocumentFile and Photo...

Comment: @NiRRaNjANRauT i have used varbinary(max) for both the document file and photo

Comment: ok...so you have to store the database files in some temp file and then display it on `JTableCellRenderer` component.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I follow your scenario very well but it sounds more to me like you should look at creating your own Cell Renderers for those columns instead of using your the default cell renderer.

Hope it helps

Comment: Presumably, the values/codes a linked to different tables and should be included in the original query